# using online file manager to upload files to your website

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration form at http://mutualpay.byethost7.com/wp/register.php?i=1.. my form action is signup.php..i created the file but it doesnt seem to work at all, when i click the signup button it loads to http://mutualpay.byethost7.com/wp/signup.php?i=2 , its like it is not executing the codes in the file

Here is my signup.php code

```
<?php session_start(); include 'dpconfig.php';
$first = $_POST['firsts'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];   
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($firsts)){
 header("Location: register.php?error=empty");
  exit();
}
if (empty($last)){
 header("Location: register.php?error=empty");
  exit();
}

 if (empty($uid)){
 header("Location: register.php?error=empty");
  exit();
}

if (empty($pwd)){
 header("Location: register.php?error=empty");
  exit();
}
else {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user (firsts, last, uid, pwd)
 VALUES ('$firsts', '$last', '$uid', '$pwd')";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
  header("Location: index.php")
}
```

its like this code are not executed, cos after clicking on the signup button, it brings a  blank page, I dont know what can be the cause, any help appreciated.Thanks

Comment: A blank page in PHP is often a sign of an error.  Check the PHP logs.  You can also enable error reporting to display the error(s) on the page.  Note also that your code is *wide open* to SQL injection, so you could be trying to execute just about anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the first empty-check you check an undefined variable (`$firsts`). I guess you meant `$first`, but php does not guess like we humans do.

change your code to

```
if (empty($first)){
```

> edit: you could also merge those 4 empty-checks into one if, in order to
>   have less code and better readability:

```
if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
    header("Location: register.php?error=empty");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: i don't have any problem with my code, the problem is why my form action is not working well

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your host, byet.
Byet uses an "antibot" system, which redirects you with javascript (mostly not executed by bots) to the same location and adding 1 to the i passed argument.
The problem is: the post arguments aren't passed when redirecting which mean that the $_POST var'll be empty.

Also check if `isset($_POST['firsts'])` and for your passed arguments to the $_POST variable or it might create undefined var errors.

Comment: The code works fine with xampp am trying to upload them with byethost and its not executing anything, what should i do please

Comment: Maybe try passing arguments thought GET (in the URL) instead of POST.

Comment: still not working, what if i change from byet to another host will it work

Comment: Did you change method="post" to method="get" in your form? And about changing host, it might work. I also recommend you telling us the errors you can see in the error logs.